# Como converter uma imagem em hexadecimal?

Tags: android

Olá, Gostaria de saber como converter uma imagem que esta no meu cartão de memória em hexadecimal.

Eu tenho um aplicativo que imprime um recibo através de uma impressora térmica, ele imprime algumas informações como data, hora, nome, valor, etc.

E eu preciso no cabeçalho imprimir o logo da empresa.

A impressora que eu uso para imprimir para ela entender a imagem e poder imprimi-la a imagem precisa estar no formato hexadecimal.

Comment: Olha tem uma gambiarra. Se você tiver um projeto aberto no editor Sublime Text 2 e nesse projeto houver uma imagem, se você clicar nela, ele mostra o hex da imagem.

Comment: Certeza que precisa ser enviada em hexadecimal? Teria como você acrescentar a instrução relevante no manual da impressora (e/ou o modelo) para a pergunta ficar mais completa?

Answer (score 1):

Primeiramente você deve convertê-la para um array de bytes, em seguida converter esse array de bytes para hexadecimal.

Verifique se essa função te ajuda:

```
final protected static char[] hexArray = "0123456789ABCDEF".toCharArray();
public static String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
    char[] hexChars = new char[bytes.length * 2];
    for ( int j = 0; j < bytes.length; j++ ) {
        int v = bytes[j] & 0xFF;
        hexChars[j * 2] = hexArray[v >>> 4];
        hexChars[j * 2 + 1] = hexArray[v & 0x0F];
    }
    return new String(hexChars);
}
```

Verifique a discussão [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655181/convert-from-byte-array-to-hex-string-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Primeiramente você deve ler o ficheiro (imagem) e convertê-lo  para um array de bytes:

```
public byte[] ler_ficheiro(String path)
{
    File file = new File(path);
    if (file.exists())
    {
      FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
      byte[] data = new byte[(int) file.length()];
      fis.read(data);
      fis.close();
      return data;

    } else
    {
       return null;
    }
}
```

Em seguida converter esse array de bytes para hexadecimal.

```
private String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes)
    {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

        for (byte b : bytes)
        {
            sb.append(String.format("%02X", b));
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Em resumo deves proceder a estes passos:

```
String imagem=...;

byte[] imagem_byte=ler_ficheiro(imagem);

if(imagem_byte!=null)
{   
   String imagem_hex=bytesToHex(imagem_byte);
}
```